# Does XMod work in Bluestacks?

Tags: bluestacks

In Bluestacks app when I am installing the XMod, the app says to root device. But how can I root Bluestacks? Please help.

Comment: Related post  [How do I install and run XModGames in BlueStacks?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-and-run-XModGames-in-BlueStacks)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it works and I have been using it for some time now.

1. Download the [XMod APK](http://www.xmodgames.com/xmod_download.php?sys=android&cid=1&type=app&page=index&pf=pc) This is official site
2. Now you need rooted bluestacks
3. Here is the link to [Rooted Bluestacks](http://droidforpc.com/how-to-root-bluestacks-app-player/) I am using
4. This bluestacks does not require rooting s it is pre-rooted
5. Install it on PC and open the XMod APK using Bluestacks

And that is basically it. I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to root your BS, to work around for XMod in Bluestack. 
Well there are tools that can really work to root your Bluestack. There is a best XDA thread that really works.

You need this tool - **BlueStacks Auto Rooter / Unlocker**

- Download this tool and Chainfire's latest SuperSU. from the link given below.
- Choose the 'CWM / TWRP / MobileODIN installable ZIP' version.
  Extract this program and add the downloaded 'UPDATE-SuperSU-*.zip' to the program folder.
- (Re)Start BlueStacks, wait until it is fully loaded, then run MultiTool and press 1.
- WARNING: DO NOT stop this tool in the middle of the rooting process.
- Follow the instructions on the screen carefully.
  Run this tool as Administrator if your current user account is restricted.
- Your BlueStacks will be restarted several times to accomplished the tasks, do not close or stop it.
- For older versions of BlueStacks, press 'Yes' immediately when prompted if you want to Quit.

**Taken Source :**

http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/xda-assist/ive-alreadyy-rooted-bluestacks-plz-tell-t2991334

**To install XMod in BlueStack : Watch this Video :**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvJ1JOx3kXQ