# Why xmod doesn't work at bluestack?

Tags: bluestacks

I am using instruction here

[Does XMod work in Bluestacks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129971/does-xmod-work-in-bluestacks)

This is the screenshot I got
[image]

Comment: you did the same as described by @Haider Amin, on the link u provided above?

Comment: Basically I uninstalled bluestack and reinstalled a rooted one

Comment: can anyone play xmod coc with bluestack as of now?